# Множественная валидация поля в Codeigniter

Tags: form, codeigniter, валидация

Столкнулся с необходимостью валидации ***одного*** поля формы по нескольким параметрам callback . Например: поле регистрации пользователя - необходимо прjверить макисмальную и минимальную длину (это встроено) и  если уже зарегистрирован пользователь. Возможно ли реализовать проверку по своим правилам одного поля по нескольким параметрам с помощью валидации форм в CI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы проверить есть ли такой пользователь уже в базе можно использовать стандартный `is_unique` библиотеки валидации Codeigniter. Например, если пользователи хранятся в таблице `users` и имя поля `username`

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', is_unique[users.username]);
```

Сами правила валидации можно использовать вместе, разделяя символов `|`. Например:

```
     $this->form_validation->set_rules(
            'username', 'Username',
            'required|min_length[3]|max_length[15]|is_unique[users.username]',
            array(
                    'required'      => 'Вы забыли указать %s.',
                    'is_unique'     => 'Пользователь %s уже существует.'
            )
    );
//Обязательное поле
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required');
//Поле повторите пароль должно совпадать с полем пароль
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('passconf', 'Password Confirmation', 'required|matches[password]');
```

Можно правила в виде массива передавать:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', array('required', 'min_length[3]', 'max_length[15]','is_unique[users.username]'));
```

Надо учитывать, что `is_unique` работает только при включеном в конфигурационном файле Query Builder классе Codeigniter. Но всегда можно создать свои правила валидации через callback. Добавьте в контроллер новую функцию и вызывайте её как правило валидации с префиксом callback:

```
    class Form extends CI_Controller {

            public function index()
            {
                    $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));

                    $this->load->library('form_validation');

                    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required|min_length[3]|max_length[15]|callback_username_check'); //вызываем собственную функцию
                    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required');
                    $this->form_validation->set_rules('passconf', 'Password Confirmation', 'required');

                    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
                    {
                            $this->load->view('myform');
                    }
                    else
                    {
                            $this->load->view('formsuccess');
                    }
            }
    //собственное правило для проверки
            public function username_check($str)
            {
//что-нибудь проверяем...

            }

    }
```

В вашей функции можно также устанавливать собственные сообщения об ошибках. Вы можете также работать с данными формы передаваемые в функцию обратного вызова и возвращать их. Если cllback возвращает отличное от логического TRUE/FALSE предполагается, что данные будут обрабатываться снова.
Можно использовать методы и из других мест, например:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules(
        'username', 'Username',
        array(
                'required', 'min_length[3]','max_length[15]',
                array($this->users_model, 'exist_user')
        )
);
```

Используем `exist_user()` метод из `Users_model` объекта. Также можно использовать просто анонимные функции:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules(
        'username', 'Username',
        array(
                'required', 'min_length[3]','max_length[15]',
                function($value)
                {
                        // Проверка $value
                }
        )
);
```

Вызываемое правило, само по себе, не является строкой и не является правилом. Это является проблемой при создании сообщений об ошибках для них. Чтобы решить эту проблему, вы можете поместить правила вторым элементом массива, где первый является именем правила:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules(
        'username', 'Username',
        array(
                'required', 'min_length[3]','max_length[15]',
                array('username_callable', array($this->users_model, 'exist_user'))
        )
);
```

С анонимной функцией:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules(
        'username', 'Username',
        array(
                'required', 'min_length[3]','max_length[15]',
                array(
                        'username_callable',
                        function($str)
                        {
                                // Проверяет валидность $str и возвращает TRUE или FALSE
                        }
                )
        )
);
```

Comment: Благодарю за ответ. Просмотрел встроенную проверку is_unique.